# Is there any way to keep on updating Django Database?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am making a Django API for Movie Ticket Booking System. The model for a ticket has got 5 fields namely

- Name of the User
- Phone Number of the User
- Date
- Time
- Status (Discussed in detail below)

The operations supported by the API are,

- GET -> get all the ticket details
- GET/ID -> get the ticket details for the specified ID
- POST -> Book a new ticket
- PUT -> Update date and time of a ticket
- DELETE/ID -> Delete a ticket with the specified ID

I have completed all the above specified functions. But Now I want to do something like,

**Mark a ticket as expired if there is a diff of 2 hours between the ticket timing and current
time.**

AND

**Delete expired tickets automatically**

I cannot find any useful resources to do the above specified tasks and am unable to think of a professional way to do so. Can anyone please explain the best approach to solve the above problems.

**NOTE:** The API will not be going LIVE. It will only run on my local machine.

Comment: "Mark a ticket as expired if there is a diff of 2 hours between the ticket timing and current time"—so make the ticket status a method and compute it on the fly.

Comment: Sorry !! I am new to Django, so I did not get you completely. Can you please elaborate a little or give some references ? That would be really helpful. Do you mean checking the status of the ticket with every GET, POST and PUT request ?

Comment: first create function which marks and deletes elements without Django and later try to do it with Django. But you have to remeber that Django (and any web page in any language) runs code only when user sends request and would need to run separated program which will periodically sends request to Django to execute this code. I would rather create separated program which does it directly in database without using Django - and it would runs in some loop which execute this function every few seconds. On Linux I would use service `cronjob` to execute this program every few minuts.